# Jmeter Variable in POST Request body and Changing it before Request is sent sending

Tags: jmeter

I have a Post HTTP request with body that has a variable in it's XML, this variable takes the hostName as a variable i.e:  123@host

```
 <Type>myType</Type>
  <FolderPath>Automation</FolderPath>
  <Description />
  <dest>123@host</dest>
  <Notes />
```

in JSR223 Pre-Processor groovy I like to change the host to ${host}.  I know I have to read the body in a string then change it like this:

```
body = body.replaceAll("host", vars.get("host") );
```

How can I read the body in a String then change the HTTP request body then place it back in the HTTP Post body before request is sent?

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for is [HTTPSamplerBase.addNonEncodedArgument()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#addNonEncodedArgument-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Example [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code to replace `host` with the relevant [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) would be something like:

```
def body = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
body = body.replaceAll('host',vars.get('host'))
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',body,'')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

Comment: This actually works perfectly! I don't know why it was not accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, by using the PreProcessor. Next you should put back that string in the same or new variable.

You can put back that body to the same variable like this:

```
vars.put("host",body);
```

Or you can change the sampler by calling:

```
sampler."method"
```

You can find all available methods on this link:
[Sampler Methods](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/Sampler.html)

Hope this helps.